# Highcharts - How can I show arrow between two dials of gauge chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I want to show arrow between two dials of the speedometer. Arrow can point to back or forth. How we can do this with Highcharts?

[image]

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rp25cqsz/2/)

Instead of black portion in fiddle result, arrow should be displayed to show movement from one point to another.

```
 {
       from: 60,
       to: 78,
       color: '#000' ,
       outerRadius: '50%',
    }
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `thickness` and use `linearGradient` as

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/s90gk1tc/15/

```
{
         thickness: 1,
           from: 60,
           to: 78,
           color: {
                    linearGradient: [300, 300, 0, 0],
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#55BF3B'],
                        [1, '#FFF']
                    ]
                } ,
           /* innerRadius: '100%', */
           outerRadius: '50%',
   }
```

Comment: it is not easy to add it :)

Comment: @Vijay Tambade, You can draw the arrow by using `Highcharts. SVGRenderer` class: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: @ppotaczek can you provide a sample?

Comment: Sure, here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f0puyxb3/, you can find an example of using `path` method to create an arrow.

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek, I will check wih SVG